# I installed Ruby on Rails and I have a problem with installing SQLite3. Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems, windows-10

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.6.0
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.7
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.8.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.2 (x86-mingw32)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.1.7
Using rack 2.0.6
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.1.7
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.7
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 5.1.7
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.1.7
Using activemodel 5.1.7
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.7
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using addressable 2.6.0
Using bindex 0.6.0
Using bundler 2.0.1
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using ffi 1.10.0 (x86-mingw32)
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using thor 0.20.3
Using railties 5.1.7
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.8.0
Using puma 3.12.1
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.1.7
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using rubyzip 1.2.2
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.7.3
Using tilt 2.0.9
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using selenium-webdriver 3.141.0
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.0
Installing sqlite3 1.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190331-11792-61sjac.rb
extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Provided configuration options:

```
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-sqlcipher
--without-sqlcipher
--with-sqlite3-config
--without-sqlite3-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-sqlcipher
--without-sqlcipher
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
```

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

In Gemfile:
  SQLite3

I have a windows 10 and I wanted to install bundle, when suddenly SQLITE 3 write Error. I searched on the internet what's wrong with this, and how to fix this problem. Because I can't run rails server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `sqlite3` & `libsqlite3-dev`

```sh
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Windows is not an ideal environment for developing Ruby on Rails. Most RoR tutorials and dependencies work best on Linux.
But you can follow this guide to install Ruby on Rails on Windows:
https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

Comment: Yes, you can use Linux in VirtualBox and there will be no problem.